# Getting some random alphabets when doing date format using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, cypress

```
const dateFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'
const date='11-20-2021'
const d=Cypress.moment(date,'mm-dd-yyyy').format(dateFormat)
cy.log(d)
```

But the output is **Fr/01/2021** instead of **20/11/2021**

Comment: try this `const dateFormat='DD/MM/yyy'`

Comment: FYI the "random alphabet" is the short version of the day (ie: Friday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In format strings, case matters. See [list of format characters](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/). `d` refers to weekday, `D` to day of the month. `m` to minute, `M` to month, and there is also a slight difference of meaning between `y` and `Y`.

```js
const dateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY'
const date='11-20-2021'
const d=moment(date,'MM-DD-YYYY').format(dateFormat)
console.log(d)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```